# Track mail sender from Mesh network

Tags: email, wifi, user-tracking

Mesh network have one router connected to WAN or Internet so IP address is allocated to that router will be exiting point for all the nodes.. and other routers will have Internet connection from that Router..

so when any malicious activity is done by someone at the time they are connected routers within Mesh WiFi network how we can track them..

Suppose anyone sends mail from mesh Network.. what are the possible ways to track down that mail sender? what Information mail company have when they detect the mail sender and try to track them.

I googled some results and it says that we can have IP address and track the mail sender but In case of Mesh network there will be single IP address(external WAN gateway) for all nodes within the Mesh

did mail providers like google only have IP address to track or they have some other Info also?

Comment: Track the mail sender by email address? Are you asking how to track the machine the email was sent from? Aside from a misunderstanding about what a 'mesh' network is, this question is very unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not what a mesh network is. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesh_networking.

I think perhaps you mean a network that uses Network Address Translation (NAT).

At the IP level, the mail provider does only see the external address of the router, this is true. Subsequent tracing has to be done by the administrator of the mail router.

There may be additional useful information to be had at the application level; it depends entirely on the application being used. (You don't tell us if this mail connection is over SMTP or HTTP or MAPI or something else, or if it is encrypted.)